# API VK getCities

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vksdk

Как с помощью Android SDK VK получить список городов по началу названия города с помощью getCities?

В документации и вообще в сети показывают как логиниться, получать список друзей и т.п, но не то, как пользоваться такого рода методами.

Comment: В [справке написано](https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk?f=4.1.%20Requests%20Syntax), как пользоваться.

Comment: Тыкните пожалуйста меня носом на место, где оно описано.

Comment: Я уже ткнул ссылкой.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду пункт 4.5, то появляется другая проблема. В параметрах необходимо так же отправлять id страны, но как именно это сделать, я не знаю.